# Factory Boy SelfAttribute is not returning what I expect

Tags: django, unit-testing, factory-boy

I have the following model that I am trying to replicate the functionality of in tests:

```py
class Client(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="client", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business_name = models.CharField(_("business name"), max_length=255, blank=True)
    business_phone = PhoneNumberField(_("business phone"), blank=True, null=True)
    business_address = models.CharField(
        _("business address"), max_length=255, blank=True
    )
    business_city = models.CharField(_("business city"), max_length=255, blank=True)
    business_state = USStateField(_("business state"), blank=True)
    business_zip = USZipCodeField(_("business zip"), max_length=255, blank=True)
    business_url = models.URLField(_("business website"), blank=True)

    @property
    def email(self):
        return self.user.email

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.business_name}"
```

The thing that is causing issues is the email property.  It should return the email address of a user.  With `DjangoModelFactory`, I am creating a user and client with the following two factories:

```py
class UserFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        django_get_or_create = ["username"]

    username = Faker("user_name")
    email = Faker("email")
    phone_number = Faker("phone_number")
    first_name = Faker("first_name")
    last_name = Faker("last_name")
    city = Faker("city")
    state = Faker("state_abbr")
    zip = Faker("zipcode_plus4")

    # these are overrideable
    password = "fakePassword"
    is_staff = False

    @classmethod
    def _create(cls, model_class, *args, **kwargs):
        """Override ``_create``"""
        kwargs["password"] = make_password(kwargs["password"])
        kwargs["is_staff"] = kwargs["is_staff"]
        return super(UserFactory, cls)._create(model_class, *args, **kwargs)



class ClientFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Client

    user = factory.SubFactory(
        UserFactory,
    )
    business_name = Faker("company")
    business_address = Faker("street_address")
    business_city = Faker("city")
    business_state = Faker("state_abbr")
    business_zip = Faker("postalcode")
    email = factory.SelfAttribute("user.email")
```

I keep getting the error `Invalid field name(s) for model Client: 'email'.` when I run the tests.  I have tried dealing with it as a lazy attribute as well, and I get the same error.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The error comes because, obviously, your `Client` model has no field `email`. You don't need to specify `email` in your `ClientFactory` because it will be taken from the email in `UserFactory`. So `client = ClientFactory.create(); client.email` should work fine

Comment: Due to requirements of dj-stripe, I need access to email as client.email, not client.user.email, which is why the property exists in the Client model.  I also did add `email = factory.SelfAttribute("user.email")` in the ClientFactory, which is where the error comes from.

Comment: `client = ClientFactory.create(); client.email` should still work though